# Why is the number output affected by a cout statement?

Tags: c++

I am making a console slots game and if I add a cout statement is changes a totally different value. The line has looks like it has nothing to do with it but if you include it won't run the for loop right , I think.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctime>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
int money = 2000;
int bet = 250;
int winStreak;
void robit(){



} 
int main() {
    int so;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int j;j<3;j++){

        int sgh = (rand()%2);
        std::cout<<sgh<<std::endl;
        switch(sgh){
            case 1:
                so =-1;
                break;
            case 2:
                so =+1;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout<<"something is wrong"<<std::endl;
        }

    }
    std::cout<<"\n"<<so;// this is the line if you comment it out the program works fine
    return 0;   
}
``
```

Comment: I forgot to say if you                                                                                                           
```                                                                                                                                           for(int j;j<=3;j++)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     it works

Comment: Neither `so` not `j` are initialized.

Answer (score 1):

1. `so` is not initialized.

   ```
   int so;
   ```
2. `j` is not initialized.

   ```
   for(int j;j<3;j++){
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your program uses the variable `j` without initializing it.

```
 for(int j;j<3;j++)
```

This causes undefined behaviour. The program can do anything.

First fix the problem & then post your problem again.

What is the initial value of `j` here?

Is it supposed to be `int j = 0`?